# Defining ZSH completion function (compdef) for multiple commands

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

I have a ZSH completion script called

```
#compdef kubens
_arguments "1: :(- $(kubectl get namespaces -o=jsonpath='{range .items[*].metadata.name}{@}{"\n"}{end}'))"
```

This provides completion to the `kubens` command. However if user provides a certain installation argument, the program is linked with `kns` name, so I am trying to provide completion for both of these commands uing the same `#compdef`.

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could use the `cmd=service` form for the `#compdef` line:

```
#compdef kubens kns=kubens
```

---

Although we can use multiple *names* for the `#compdef` line, `cmd=service` forms could be used when the `cmd` behaves the same way as the `service`:

> `#compdef name ... [ -{p|P} pattern ... [ -N name ... ] ]`
>
> The file will be made autoloadable and the function defined in it will be called when completing *names*, each of which is either the name of a command whose arguments are to be completed ...
>   ...
>   Each *name* may also be of the form ‘`cmd=service`’. When completing the command *cmd*, the function typically behaves as if the command (or special context) *service* was being completed instead.
>
> -- [`zshcompsys(1): Completion System, INITIALIZATION, Autoloaded files, #compdef`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-compdef_002c-use-of-by-compinit)

Comment: Thanks, it looks like this information was somewhat buried in the manual and no Google search result revealed it. I hope this question helps others.